# UITextField to Float

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I Have a textfield and I need the user to put a number in there, this number I need to transform into a float value and take it to another view. I can't find my error... Xcode says it is on the "`float valor = [[_inserir.text ] floatvalue];`"line. If somebody could find where is my error, thanks.

first view .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CedulasFirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inserir;
- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender;

@end
```

first view .m:  (the underline before my variable name, xcode put it by itself, taking it out doesn't change anything)

```
#import "CedulasFirstViewController.h"
#import "CedulasSecondViewController.h"

@interface CedulasFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation CedulasFirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender {

    float valor = [[_inserir.text ] floatvalue];

    CedulasSecondViewController *second [[[CedulasSecondViewController alloc] init]];

    second.valor = self.valor;

}
@end
```

second view .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CedulasSecondViewController : UIViewController{


}

@end
```

second view .m:

```
#import "CedulasSecondViewController.h"

@interface CedulasSecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation CedulasSecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *numberFromTF [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", valor];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Thanks

EDIT:

if someone could explain me why xcode says to put this underline before the variable

Comment: Do not use string formats nor call `floatValue` to convert to/from user entered data for float values. It won't work in many locales. Use  `NSNumberFormatter` to properly parse entered numbers or to display a value to the user. This will allow users enter numbers in a format they are used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do here.

First, you've created a property in `CedulasFirstViewController.h`, so you need to synthesize it in `CedulasFirstViewController.m`.  In `CedulasFirstViewController.m`, beneath the line `@implementation CedulasFirstViewController`, type

```
@synthesize inserir;
```

Then, in the line `float valor = [[_inserir.text ] floatvalue];`, there are a couple errors.  You're treating your property like an instance variable, so instead of `_inserir.text` you should use `self.inserir.text`.  Also, you should remove the inner pair of brackets, because brackets are used for when functions are being performed, and there's no function being performed in `self.inserir.text`.  `self.inserir.text` (or `_inserir.text`, for that matter) is simply an object.

All this means that the line producing the error should look like this:

```
float valor = [self.inserir.text floatvalue];
```

There seem to be some other problems with this code, but if you ask about them those should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This following function will convert your text into required format.

```
 float val=[_inserir.text floatvalue];
 int val=[_inserir.text intvalue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error it's:

```
float valor = [[_inserir text ] floatValue];
```

Comment: No, it should be `float valor = [_inserir.text floatValue];`

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried both ways, on both an error appeared "Expected Identifier"

Comment: Try `float valor = [self.inserir.text floatValue];`

Comment: inserir should be automatically synthesized to _inserir.

Comment: @rmaddy that worked, but now another error appeared... on the CedulasSecondViewController *second
[[[CedulasSecondViewController alloc] init]];` line... it's "Size of array has non-integer type 'CedulasSecondViewController *'"

Comment: Shall be [[CedulasSecondViewController alloc] init]

Comment: You need to proof read. You have no `=` sign and too many brackets on that line.

Comment: God... I'm sorry guys... I'm felling so idiot! hahahaha thanks